# Issue with showing ToolTip window manually

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, popup, tooltip

I have developed a control and used this control as ToolTip with using native methods to register the control as tooltip.

I have configured the created control as ToolTip for the control through registering the tooltip control handle and handle of control in which the tooltip has to be shown with below code,

```
WindowsAPI.SendMessage(this.Handle, (int)TTM.TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, ref m_toolInfo);
```

This works fine, and tooltip window is showing automatically in mousehover of the control.

And also i have tried to show the tooltip manually without registering to any controls like below code,

```
WindowsAPI.SendMessage(hWnd, (int)TTM.TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, ref ti);
WindowsAPI.SendMessage(hWnd, (int)TTM.TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, 1, ref ti);
```

But after showing the tooltip window with above code, default process of showing the tooltip in control's mousehover is also not working.

May i know, why showing the tooltip manually stops the working of default tooltip showing?

**Edit**
Please refer to the code block used for tooltip in the link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5mR240pVB51ZFZpT2dwQ2pxeTQ/view?usp=sharing

Regards,
Amal Raj U.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] to simulate the problem. Without having mcve, just some guesses can be shared.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - code block of my sample added in edit